# Format special keywords such as 'arguments' in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

In WebStorm the special keyword `arguments` is formatted in the same color as the local variables of the function. The instructor I'm following is using VS Code theme where `arguments` (blue and italic). Is it possible to achieve this in WebStorm? Is it possible to this in WebStorm?

WebStorm and Darcula:

[image: Darcula example]

VS Code and codewithmosh:

[image]

Under Editor -> Color Scheme -> JavaScript the closest I could get was to change the foreground color of 'Parameter' (see below). but I only want the formatting to target `arguments` and presumably other special keywords.

I'm using WebStorm (version 2022.3) and the Default Darcula theme

[image]